# how to give input to secondary prompt which comes after running a script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, solaris

```
$ cat messing_script.sh
#!/bin/sh
ext=`date '+%m%d%H%M'`
host=`hostname`
datalog=/export/admin/imsimta
dire=`date '+%m%d'`
datadir=$datalog/$host/$dire
if [ ! -d $datadir ]
then
        mkdir -p $datadir  2> /dev/null
fi
dir1=/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/sbin/
cd     $dir1
sleep     5
./imsimta qm
sleep 2
top > $datadir/$ext 2> /dev/null
exit
```

Comment: when I run this script, ./imsimta qm will create another prompt ie. qm.maint>
and on this prompt I need to run top > $datadir/$ext 2> /dev/null cmd.
But the script is not working after qm.maint> prompt.

Comment: # cat messing_script.sh
#!/bin/sh

ext=`date '+%m%d%H%M'`
host=`hostname`
datalog=/export/admin/imsimta
dire=`date '+%m%d'`
datadir=$datalog/$host/$dire
if [ ! -d $datadir ]
then
        mkdir -p $datadir  2> /dev/null
fi




dir1=/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/sbin/
cd $dir1

sleep 5

./imsimta qm

sleep 2
top > $datadir/$ext 2> /dev/null
exit

Comment: Try something like `echo "Second answer" | ./imsimta qm`

Comment: Redirecting `top` to a file is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

`imsimta`, if it spawns a shell, probably supports an option to run a string.  Try one of:

```
./imsimta qm -c "top > $datadir/$ext"
```

or

```
./imsimta qm << EOF > $datadir/$ext
top 
EOF
```

The second case is probably easier as `echo top | ./imsimta qm`, but the heredoc makes it easier to expand as needed.  Neither of these is guaranteed to work, and they depend on how `imsimta` is implemented.  I strongly recommend not discarding stderr until you have a working script.